# MYSQL search WHERE VALUE matches with the comma split string

Tags: mysql, search

I have a field **PROPERTY_TYPE** in my table **Property_types** containing a single value such as Residential, Commercial, or office.

When running the query

```
select * from property_types where property type like '%Residential,office%'
```

To get all the properties, but it returns nothing.

How should I rewrite the query to select ONLY the residential and office types and not all property types?

I don't want to use OR Operator i.e `WHERE property_type = 'office' OR property_type = 'residential'` because there are a lot of property types with other complex query operators.

I tried FIND_IN_SET, SEARCH OPERATOR, but it didn't work anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM property_types 
WHERE `property type` LIKE '%Residential%'
   OR `property type` LIKE '%office%'
```

For further troubleshooting, please share input tables with samples and the expected output table.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use OR Operator because there are a lot of property types with other complex query operators. is there any other workaround?

Comment: what about `WHERE \`property type\` IN ['Residential', 'office']`? @Kayani